# Hole Punshing __ Sending to local loop works but sending to external ip not

Tags: c#, p2p, windows-firewall, hole-punching

I spend hours trying to implement [Hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) in C# , my project need a connection to be made directly between me ( server ) and other slaves (peers) , I have third party server that I'm using to keep track external IPs which belongs to the server and peers .

the Code I managed to write until now works fine when I supply an internal IP for the server ( loopback or (0.0.0.0)) but it don't when I put my external ip .. it give no exceptions , but when using a tool like [packet sender](https://packetsender.com/) to test it , the server recieve the datagram just from the loopback , not my external .

here my **Server** implementation :

```
class Program
{
    static byte[] dataToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test");

    // get the ip and port number where the client will be listening on
    static IPEndPoint GetClientInfo()
    {
        // wait for client to send data
        using (UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(11000))
        {
            IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("188.247.78.18") , 11000);
            byte[] receive_byte_array = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);

            return groupEP;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var info = GetClientInfo(); // get client info

        /* NOW THAT WE HAVE THE INFO FROM THE CLIENT WE ARE GONG TO SEND
           DATA TO IT FROM SCRATCH!. NOTE THE CLIENT IS BEHIND A NAT AND
           WE WILL STILL BE ABLE TO SEND PACKAGES TO IT
        */

        // create a new client. this client will be created on a 
        // different computer when I do readl udp punch holing
        UdpClient newClient = ConstructUdpClient(info);


        Console.WriteLine(info.Address.ToString());
        // send data
        newClient.Send(dataToSend, dataToSend.Length);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    // Construct a socket with the info received from the client
    static UdpClient ConstructUdpClient(IPEndPoint clientInfo)
    {
        var ip = clientInfo.Address.ToString();
        var port = clientInfo.Port;

        // this is the part I was missing!!!!
        // the local end point must match. this should be the ip this computer is listening on
        // and also the port            
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 11000));

        // lastly we are missing to set the end points. (ip and port client is listening on)

        // the connect method sets the remote endpoints
        client.Connect(ip, port);

        return client;
    }
}
```

and this is my **Client** implementation :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ipOfServer = "188.247.78.18"; //this is my external Ip and it doesn't work giving me nothing in the server Console ( but if I replaced it with 127.0.0.1 server console response)
        int portServerIsListeningOn = 11000;

        // send data to server
        Socket sending_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPAddress send_to_address = IPAddress.Parse(ipOfServer);
        IPEndPoint sending_end_point = new IPEndPoint(send_to_address, portServerIsListeningOn);
        sending_socket.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test"), sending_end_point);

        // get info
        var port = sending_socket.LocalEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[1];

        // now wait for server to send data back
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(port));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        sending_socket.Receive(buffer); // <----- we can receive data now!!!!!
    }
}
```

how to make this works , and how to test it to make sure that the server working in my pc from outside ?

Comment: You can't bind to an IP address unless it belongs to the local interface. It's also not a good test to try and send to the external IP address from the internal network. Routers/NATs forward packets differently depending on where it originated. If your challenge is finding the external IP address of an interface do a search on STUN.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion , unfortunetly STUN reports "UdpBlocked" for my external IP 
@sipwiz I'm moving to use UPnP to achieve this , please look at this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237337/c-sharp-upnp-not-seems-to-be-work